# Как преобразовать размерность части массива?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

```
A = np.ones((14, 32, 3, 3))
```

Пусть у нас имеется 4-мерный NumPy массив.

Можно ли применить функцию `np.ravel`, или аналогичную ей, вдоль последних трех осей массива `А`?

Tо есть, в итоге должна получиться матрица с размерами `(14, 32 * 3 * 3))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно воспользоваться методом `ndarray.reshape()`:

```
A = np.ones((14, 32, 3, 3))
res = A.reshape(-1, np.prod(A.shape[1:]))
```

результат:

```
res.shape
>>> (14, 288)
```

Comment: когда 100k планируете?

Comment: @Danis, не знаю, работа сильно отвлекает :-D

Comment: я работаю учеником а вы кем работаете?

Comment: @Danis Думаю, этот вопрос многих интересует ))